# PayPal response missing tax

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm working on an NVP API integration and the entire payment process is working properly.  The response I get from PayPal upon completion doesn't provide all the proper information.

Here is the code I am sending PayPal

```
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=44.48
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT=40
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT=4.48
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHPPINGAMT=0
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INVNUM=5193f0cca7e70
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=USD
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC=Test payment desc
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0=40
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0=1
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0=Test item
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER0=5191cd62462fb
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC0=Test item desc
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHPPINGAMT0=0.00
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT0=4.48
&RETURNURL=[REMOVED]
&CANCELURL=[REMOVED]
&BRANDNAME=Some Con 2014
&CUSTOMERSERVICENUMBER=000-000-0000
```

The order goes through and proper payment is processed, however the information given back is missing the tax information.

```
[TOKEN] => EC-1KS56755YX305151R
[SUCCESSPAGEREDIRECTREQUESTED] => false
[TIMESTAMP] => 2013-05-15T20:48:42Z
[CORRELATIONID] => 553a6a47ec1
[ACK] => Success
[VERSION] => 98
[BUILD] => 5956203
[INSURANCEOPTIONSELECTED] => false
[SHIPPINGOPTIONISDEFAULT] => false
[PAYMENTINFO_0_TRANSACTIONID] => 1XV29769HY7702037
[PAYMENTINFO_0_TRANSACTIONTYPE] => expresscheckout
[PAYMENTINFO_0_PAYMENTTYPE] => instant
[PAYMENTINFO_0_ORDERTIME] => 2013-05-15T20:48:41Z
[PAYMENTINFO_0_AMT] => 44.48
[PAYMENTINFO_0_FEEAMT] => 1.59
[PAYMENTINFO_0_TAXAMT] => 0.00
[PAYMENTINFO_0_CURRENCYCODE] => USD
[PAYMENTINFO_0_PAYMENTSTATUS] => Completed
[PAYMENTINFO_0_PENDINGREASON] => None
[PAYMENTINFO_0_REASONCODE] => None
[PAYMENTINFO_0_PROTECTIONELIGIBILITY] => Eligible
[PAYMENTINFO_0_PROTECTIONELIGIBILITYTYPE] => ItemNotReceivedEligible,UnauthorizedPaymentEligible
[PAYMENTINFO_0_SECUREMERCHANTACCOUNTID] => 3JTQYBPNDRWES
[PAYMENTINFO_0_ERRORCODE] => 0
[PAYMENTINFO_0_ACK] => Success
```

Why is PAYMENTINFO_0_TAXAMT coming back 0 when it is 4.48?

I'm also having an issue where the email that is sent upon purchase from PayPal is not listing the items purchased and only a general total amount.  Notice description is not the item description but the overall order description.

```
-----------------------------------
Purchase Details
-----------------------------------

Description: Test payment desc
Unit price: $44.48 USD
Qty: 1
Amount: $44.48 USD


Subtotal: $44.48 USD
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tax is not being displayed because it is not getting passed over in your DoExpressCheckoutPayment API call.  I checked the logs, and I only show that you passed it over in the SetExpressCheckout API call, but not the DoExpressCheckoutPayment API call.  You would need to pass it over in the Do EC call if you are wanting it returned. This is also what is happening with your description.  It is not getting passed over in the Do EC call.

Comment: Updated DoExpressCheckoutPayment API call and all is working as intended now.  Thank you for your help.